# Querying web-page through Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

In my company, I am able to get access to some data through a dedicated web app/page. I know that SAP is behind however I don't have access to it directly.

I only have access through the following web address : 
    [http://mycompany:57600/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd!3aportal_content](http://mycompany:57600/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd!3aportal_content!2fcom.sap.pct!2fplatform_add_ons!2fcom.sap.ip.bi!2fiViews!2fcom.sap.ip.bi.bex?QUERY=GLO_COC001_001&VARIABLE_SCREEN=&DUMMY=2&LANGUAGE=EN&BI_COMMAND_1-BI_COMMAND_TYPE=SET_VARIABLES_STATE&BI_COMMAND_1-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_1-VARIABLE_TYPE=VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING&BI_COMMAND_1-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_1-VARIABLE_TYPE-VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING=&BI_COMMAND_1-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_1-VARIABLE=V010FISCYEARMSO&BI_COMMAND_2-BI_COMMAND_TYPE=SET_VARIABLES_STATE&BI_COMMAND_2-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_2-VARIABLE_TYPE=VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING&BI_COMMAND_2-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_2-VARIABLE_TYPE-VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING=&BI_COMMAND_2-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_2-VARIABLE=V010FISCPER3MSO&BI_COMMAND_3-BI_COMMAND_TYPE=SET_VARIABLES_STATE&BI_COMMAND_3-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_3-VARIABLE_TYPE=VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING&BI_COMMAND_3-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_3-VARIABLE_TYPE-VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING=P.013628&BI_COMMAND_3-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_3-VARIABLE=V010PROJECTMSO&BI_COMMAND_4-BI_COMMAND_TYPE=SET_VARIABLES_STATE&BI_COMMAND_4-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_4-VARIABLE_TYPE=VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING&BI_COMMAND_4-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_4-VARIABLE_TYPE-VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING=&BI_COMMAND_4-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_4-VARIABLE=V010WBS_GUIDMSO&BI_COMMAND_5-BI_COMMAND_TYPE=SET_VARIABLES_STATE&BI_COMMAND_5-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_5-VARIABLE_TYPE=VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING&BI_COMMAND_5-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_5-VARIABLE_TYPE-VARIABLE_INPUT_STRING=&BI_COMMAND_5-VARIABLE_VALUES-VARIABLE_VALUE_5-VARIABLE=V010PS_RESPNOSO&&USE_PERSONALIZATION=&)

This produces a table-like web page containing the data I need. Is there a way to directly fetch this data within python without the need to go trough this web page ?

Comment: yes, for example with the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library

Comment: your question has nothing to do with SAP as you have no access to it, you just need usual web-scraper

Answer (score 1):

Use pyrfc and follow the instruction there: [PyRfc](https://sap.github.io/PyRFC/)

Once you make the connection, you can call standard RFC function in SAP "RFC_READ_TABLE" and supply the table name.